# is product of norms convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Is a function of the form 
$f(x) = \|x\|_1\|x\|_2$
convex in x? I have tried plotting it in wolfram alpha and it appears convex, althought I ahve not been able to show it yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't.  Consider (for functions on $\mathbb R$)
$$ x(t) = \cases{1/n^3 & for $0 \le t \le n^4$\cr 0 & otherwise\cr}, \ y(t) = \cases{n^3 & for $-1/n^4 < t < 0$\cr 0 & otherwise\cr} $$
We have $\|x\|_1 = n$, $\|y\|_1 = 1/n$, $\|x\|_2 = 1/n$, $\|y\|_2 = n$, so $f(x) = f(y) = 1$.  However, $\|(x+y)/2\|_1  > n/2$ and $\|(x+y)/2\|_2 > n/2$,
so $f((x+y)/2) > n^2/4 > 1$ if $n > 2$.

EDIT: it seems that $f$ is convex on ${\mathbb R}^3$ but not on ${\mathbb R}^4$.
Counterexample for ${\mathbb R}^4$: $x = (1,0,0,0)$, $y = (0,1/5,1/5,1/5)$,
$f((x+y)/2) =  .4233202099 < (f(x)+f(y))/2 = .6039230485$.

EDIT: Oops, wrong way.  Try $x = (1,0,0,0)$, $y = (.9,.07,.07,.07)$,
$f((x+y)/2) = 1.004288519  > (f(x)+f(y))/2 = 1.004012120$.

Comment: thanks. the counterexample nails it. I was trying to show that the Hessian is PSD but was running into trouble.

Comment: Wait, your counterexample for $\mathbb R^4$ isn't. $f((x+y)/2) < (f(x) + f(y))/2$ is perfectly consistent with $f$ being a convex function.

Comment: However, it is true that $f$ is quite nonconvex along the straight-line path $(1,0,0,0) + \alpha(-\frac32,1,1,1)$ for $\alpha<0.049$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** we have $(\lVert x\rVert_1+\lVert y\rVert_1)((\lVert x\rVert_2+\lVert y\rVert_2)\geqslant 0$. Multiply this by $\alpha(1-\alpha)\geqslant 0$. It's the difference between $$\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)\mbox{ and  }\alpha \lVert x\rVert_1+(1-\alpha)\lVert y\rVert_1))(\alpha \lVert x\rVert_2+(1-\alpha)\lVert y\rVert_2).$$

Comment: Oops, no it isn't.  Note that the more general statement, that the product of two nonnegative convex functions is convex, is false.

Comment: I have seen the specific condition that you mentioned before (reversed for concave functions). But as you pointed out, it need hot hold in general.